# Editing the inside of an object

Tags: edit-mode

How can I get my view inside of an object so I can edit the inside in edit mode? For example, you create a block, but you want to edit how it looks inside (like a house), how can I do that?

Comment: @Random Don't write a status (*[solved]*) or tags (*editing*) in the title. If you receive an answer which solves the problem, mark the answer as accepted. If the question is closed, there is no need for further actions.

Comment: @Leander I will "mark" it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a house,

Start from a plane, make the outer shell and then work on the smaller detail with new planes/circles whatever. it's not recommended to make a house from just 1 Cube.

Answer (score 1):

To view an object from the inside, you have to be in the perspective camera mode, because you are not able to "enter" the object with an orthogonal camera.

The shortcut *Numpad 5* let you switch between orthogonal camera and perspective camera.

also important is, to have backface culling disabled or else you wont see any backfaces . You can find it in the property panel in the 3dView (shortcut *N*).

[image: Backface Culling]

But if you really want to edit a inside of an object, I would recommend to create faces which are pointing inward to prevent issues while rendering.

Comment: Another way is to use Alt-B to cut away a section of the mesh in the viewport. Using Alt-B again will then bring it back.

Answer (score 0):

You could try hiding the outside mesh in *Edit Mode* by pressing <kbd>H</kbd> but that will probably take a lot of selecting, though this is the only solution if you really wanna work in 2D view

Comment: I don't quite get how is 2D view related here but hiding the outside part of mesh can work (if it consists of 2 parts so to be available for being hidden like that of course, otherwise mesh itself will just become invisible)